# How to implement scoped function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, scope

```
function parent($key)
{
     function son()
     {
         global $key;
     }
}
```

I want to achieve this:

2. `son` can access the `$key` of `parent`

As it's quite a simple function,I don't want to change `parent` into a class

OK,I've been told that `function` are global anyway.Is there a way for `son` to get `$key` of `parent` then?

Comment: Can't you just pass `$key` to `son()` as an argument?

Comment: I can't,because it's called by `usort` this way:`usort($arr,'son');`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you exactly need? Post more code. I don't understand how `usort` prevents passing that argument.

Comment: You can have a look at the last version of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PHP 5.3 you can do:

```
function parent($key) {
    $son = function() use (&$key) {
        var_dump($key);
    };
    $son();
}
parent('foo');
```

About usort -- are you looking for something like this?

```
$key = 'foo';
$arr = array(
    array(0, 'foo' => 1),
    array(1, 'foo' => 4),
    array(2, 'foo' => -2),
);

usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use (&$key) {
    $a = $a[$key];
    $b = $b[$key];
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: But I need the `$key` together with those populated by `usort`

Answer (score 1):

All functions  in PHP have the `global scope` - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined **inside** and vice versa.

Refer the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you consider OOP approach? Define class with methods using different modifiers: public/private... Of course I'm simplify, but going this direction will help to achieve your goal.

If you insist of not using OOP, but still need this happens read this: http://www.steike.com/code/php-closures/ and this http://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures. Since closures it's only way I know how you can do it without OOP, but using functional programming.

Comment: No,it's just too simple.Besides,the current project is not a OO one.OOP is good,but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in OOP and you can not create one function inside another. However, one way may be like this:

```
// make sure that parent function exists
if (function_exists('parent'))
{
   // ok fine, now create the son function
   function son()
   {
       global $key;
   }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to define `$key` as `global`,it's nowhere else used at all

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `usort()`, can this work?

```
$arr = array('foo', 'bar', 'tork', 'zug');

usort($arr, 'mysort');

function mysort($a, $b) {
    $a = do_something_with_a($a);
    $b = do_something_with_b($b);

    return strcmp($a, $b);
}

function do_something_with_a($val) {
    return strrev($val);
}
function do_something_with_b($val) {
    return strrev($val);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: My purpose is simply to pass the necessary parameters to the `mysort` in your example.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to use a global variable, unless you want to add the value you need to pass to every item of your array and strip it away in the comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding, you need a function that generates custom sorting function for you, depending on the passed parameter, along the lines of

```
function sorter($param) {
    return function($a, $b) use($param) {
        if($param == 'asc') return $a - $b;
        if($param = 'desc') return $b - $a;
    };
}

$a = array(1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4);
usort($a, sorter('asc'));
print_r($a);
usort($a, sorter('desc'));
print_r($a);
```

(php 5.3 only)